# How to iterate through JSON object in Python and get KEY?

Tags: python-3.x

I have JSON:

```
{"invoice_no":[ {"name":"Invoice 21342","start_offset": "10", "end_offset": "25"},{"name":"Invoice No:","start_offset": "10", "end_offset": "25"}],"invoice_date":[ {"name":"From day","start_offset": "10", "end_offset": "25"}]}
```

I want to iterate through 'invoice_no' object and get key of each item inside this object. To finaly have something like:

```
jsonObject["invoice_no"][key]["name"]
jsonObject["invoice_no"][key]["start_offset"]
```

I do not want to get just attribute names or values. I need key to make a pair

With PHP this is trivial, in Python I spent hours without success.

EDIT:
Final code after your help:

```
import json
jsonString = '{"invoice_no":[ {"name":"Invoice 21342","start_offset": "35", "end_offset": "25"},{"name":"Invoice No:","start_offset": "10", "end_offset": "25"}],"invoice_date":[ {"name":"From day","start_offset": "10", "end_offset": "25"}]}'
jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

# get keys of jsonObject
for item in jsonObject:
 # loop through each list
 for list_item in jsonObject[item]:
  if list_item['name'] == "Invoice 21342":
   print (list_item['start_offset'])
```

This much, much, much more easier in PHP...

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I'd like to loop through x['invoice_no']['name'] and if this element == 'blah blah' then y = x['invoice_no'][key']['start_offset']

Comment: That isn't an output - that is code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of your `jsonObject` where the values of each item is a list. Then iterate through each list of dictionaries and get the key-value pair. You can do something like this

```
# get keys of jsonObject
for item in jsonObject:
  # loop through each list
  for list_item in jsonObject[item]:
    # for each list get the key,value pair
    for keys in list_item:
      print (f"(Key,Value)=>({keys}, {list_item[keys]})")
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this is not a key. This is just element name and value. So I have if f"{list_item[keys]}" == "Invoice 21342": and how to get 'start_offset' from same object? I need pointer to this element

Comment: So if I understand your questions correctly, you want the object where `name` = `"Invoice 21342" ` and get all the other properties, in that case you can just do `if list_item["name"] == "Invoice 21342":`, then `list_item` will be your object of intrest.

Comment: Yep, this is what I wanted - thank you very much for help!